# How to make textarea same height as select while still being reponsive?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a form that I am developing and while I can get the form fields to be responsive for width, the textarea box is slightly taller than the select field to the right. How can I make these two the same height while keeping both responsive for mobile?

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/aarmfield/full/ZvWRNZ/) of the form. Below is the code:

```
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label for="00NW0000001Zjiv" class="control-label" style="font-weight:300">Truck Model(s)</label>
              <textarea id="00NW0000001Zjiv" name="00NW0000001Zjiv" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" rows="5"></textarea><span class="help-block bg-danger"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="control-group">
            <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
              <label for="00NW0000001Zjje" class="control-label" style="font-weight:300">State(s) in which the truck(s) run</label>
              <select id="00NW0000001Zjje" name="00NW0000001Zjje" multiple="multiple" class="form-control input-lg">
                <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
                <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
                <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="California">California</option>
                <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
                <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
                <option value="Delaware">Delaware</option>
                <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                <option value="Hawaii">Hawaii</option>
                <option value="Idaho">Idaho</option>
                <option value="Illinois">Illinois</option>
                <option value="Indiana">Indiana</option>
                <option value="Iowa">Iowa</option>
                <option value="Kansas">Kansas</option>
                <option value="Kentucky">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="Louisiana">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="Maine">Maine</option>
                <option value="Maryland">Maryland</option>
                <option value="Massachusetts">Massachusetts</option>
                <option value="Michigan">Michigan</option>
                <option value="Minnesota">Minnesota</option>
                <option value="Mississippi">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="Missouri">Missouri</option>
                <option value="Montana">Montana</option>
                <option value="Nebraska">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="Nevada">Nevada</option>
                <option value="New Hampshire">New Hampshire</option>
                <option value="New Jersey">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="New Mexico">New Mexico</option>
                <option value="New York">New York</option>
                <option value="North Carolina">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="North Dakota">North Dakota</option>
                <option value="Ohio">Ohio</option>
                <option value="Oklahoma">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="Oregon">Oregon</option>
                <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                <option value="Rhode Island">Rhode Island</option>
                <option value="South Carolina">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="South Dakota">South Dakota</option>
                <option value="Tennessee">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                <option value="Utah">Utah</option>
                <option value="Vermont">Vermont</option>
                <option value="Virginia">Virginia</option>
                <option value="Washington">Washington</option>
                <option value="West Virginia">West Virginia</option>
                <option value="Wisconsin">Wisconsin</option>
                <option value="Wyoming">Wyoming</option>
              </select><span class="help-block bg-danger"></span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you produce a more minimal example of your problem. Right now, you have a lot of extra code in there that's not directly relevant to your question.

Comment: I edited it. The submission required that I put code in if I was putting a link to codepen.io, and I didn't really know how to link all the CSS. I figured people could click on the codepen and see what the issue is.

Comment: There is thing called 'height' in CSS. Use it.

Comment: Setting a block element to a percentage height will only result in a worst result. Setting a static height is not mobile responsive. Do you have a specific recommendation that would fix the issue?

Comment: In your codepen the height of the textarea and select doesn't seem to be responsive for mobile? They seem static as is, so I don't see why you have an issue with setting the height with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by giving manually height to textarea. So give height to textarea on media queries.

In this way you would be able to achieve the responsiveness as well.

I hope this might help you 
[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/neelshah14/73cyorL1/10/)

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="left">
            <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name" id="first-name" required="required"  />

        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <label for="details">Details</label>
            <textarea name="details" placeholder="Details" id="details" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

        textarea { height: calc(100% - 0.75em); /* 100% fill height, minus height of details label */ }
    }
```